# Como eu poderia fazer para pegar todos os dias do mês atual?

Tags: postgresql

Primeiramente bom dia pessoal, eu gostaria de uma ajuda em conseguir filtrar todos os dias do mês atual, onde eu conseguiria pegar desde o dia 1 até o 30 ou 31 do mês atual, onde eu não definiria qual o mês que eu quero e sim o que está na maquina.

Como eu poderia fazer uma busca sem um mês fixo?

```
base_cliente_comprou (ID) AS (
    SELECT * FROM tb_pedido 
    INNER JOIN base ON cliente = ped_cli_id
    WHERE ped_data BETWEEN '2020-07-01 00:00:00' AND '2020-07-31 23:59:59' AND ped_cli_id NOT IN (cliente)
```

)

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: só o mês, ou o mês e ano?

Comment: Por exemplo: `ped_data >= date_trunc('month', CURRENT_DATE) AND ped_data < (date_trunc('month', CURRENT_DATE) + interval '1 month')`

Comment: Olá gente, muito obrigado pela resposta, eu testei dos dois jeitos que vocês me mandaram e deu super certo, muito obrigado, já estou aplicando no meu código. Forte abraço...

Comment: Claudio Lopes, eu precisava do ano e esqueci de perguntar também, mas a resposta do Marcos lá embaixo acaba por pegar o ano também, bom muito obrigado mesmo assim ;)

Comment: Apenas para o mês corrente pode simplificar para: `data_trunc('month', CURRENT_DATE) = date_trunc('month', ped_data)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom dia,

Pelo que entendi, você quer todos os registros para um determinado mês. Se for esse o caso, utilize algo assim:

```
base_cliente_comprou (ID) AS (
    SELECT * FROM tb_pedido 
    INNER JOIN base ON cliente = ped_cli_id
    WHERE 
    extract('month' from ped_data) = extract('month' from current_date)
    and extract ('year' from ped_data) = extract('year' from current_date)
)
```

Comment: A Marcos, obrigado, testei a forma que você mandou e funcionou muito bem também, muito obrigado pela ajuda, forte abraço...

Comment: Disponha, peço apenas que marque a resposta como aceita, com isso, outros usuários na mesma situação serão ajudados também. Abraços